# Jquery fetch style attribute and assign negative value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there a way to fetch an inline style and assign a negative value to it?

I have the following:

```
<div class="info" style="top: 52px"> .... </div>
```

The `top`-attribute is added dynamically, but for some display/layout issues I need to "invert" it in some cases, so that the value is `top: -52px`

So I tried this:

```
var divHeight = $('.info').attr('style');
$('.additional').attr('style', divHeight )
```

This only adds additional 52px to it, but as mentioned before, it needs to be inverted to `top:-52px`

Comment: `$('.additional').attr('style', 'left: -' + divHeight);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method rather than style (don't think jquery by itself has this method, at least not as per their [doc](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/))

```
var divHeight = -parseFloat( $('.info').css('top') );
$('.additional').css('top', divHeight + "px" )
```